# Rails - Can you use collection_radio_buttons with options_for_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a select in a form which works fine:

```
<%= f.select(:scan_type, options_for_select(Scan::SCAN_TYPES, task.scan_type)) %>
```

I want to convert it to a set of radio buttons, as there are only a few options. Is there a way to use `options_for_select` with `collection_radio_buttons`?

I'm just using a simple array for my options, i.e. in scan.rb -

`SCAN_TYPES = ['roll', 'single']`

My first approach was to try

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons(:scan_type, options_for_select(Scan::SCAN_TYPES, object.scan_type)) %>
```

But I'm not providing all the arguments. I'm at a loss to see what needs to be added.

Comment: `f.collection_radio_buttons(:scan_type, Scan::SCAN_TYPES.to_a, :last, :first, checked: f.object.scan_type)` Try this

Comment: Hi Vrushali - thanks, that seems like a really good start - the buttons are there, but I'm only getting the first letter of each option. What do the :first and :last symbols do? Also, SCAN_TYPES is already an array so the .to_a is not necessary.

Comment: can you paste Scan::SCAN_TYPES? basically, it needs two dimensional array and it will iterate through all elements and call first and last method on each element

Comment: pasted in. each element is just a string. Calling :humanize twice seems to do the trick. Is it just a case of finding a method that doesn't screw things up? Seems a bit weird :)

Comment: `f.collection_radio_buttons(:scan_type, Scan::SCAN_TYPES.map{|s| [s, s] }, checked: f.object.scan_type)` Try this

Comment: Yep that does it - thanks, I kinda understand now - you're mapping each element in the array into an array pair, then using :last and :first as the label and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(:scan_type, Scan::SCAN_TYPES.map{|s| [s, s] }, checked: f.object.scan_type)
```

Check this